# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server full disk encryption

Tags: server, system-installation, encryption, 18.04

I was installing ubuntu 18.04 lts server (`ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso`). I need full disk encryption. But it is missing here. How can I get the LVM and full disk encryption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the 18.04 server release notes on

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server

you will need to use the alternate installer to configure LVM (also RAID, multipath, vlans, bonds, or the ability to re-using existing partitions) on installation. You can download it from:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/

Comment: For example, at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/, `ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso` is an example of one of the alternate installers? The only difference in the list of installers seems to be architecture, none of the installers specifically state "alternate".

Comment: yes, those are the alternate installers. However, seems like the standard installer has been greatly improved. From above link: "As of 18.04.1, the Subiquity server installer now supports LVM, RAID, vlans, and bonds."